# How to limit the results of a Spring Repository with custom query

Tags: spring

I am using a Spring repository to query a database, but because of the nature of my application I need to use a custom `@Query` in order to `JOIN FETCH` lazy collections.

This process works fine, but now I need to limit the result to a single record. I understand that Spring has the notion of `findFirst` or `findTop1` in the method names, but this does not appear to work when you have a custom query.

How can I use a custom query and limit the result to 1 record when using a Spring repository?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a Pageable param in your query method

```
@Query("select e from Entity e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.list")
public Page<Entity> find(Pageable pageable);
```

and call the method passing the object

```
repository.find(new PageRequest(0, 1));
```

Comment: This sometimes works, but the way spring generates the count query will often means that custom fetch joins don't work with paging unless you use a custom count query. http://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/fetch-query-not-working-spring-data-jpa-pageable